# SQL distinct columns with a concat of unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, concatenation

In SQL Server, I have a simple view called `v_master_server_list`.

Server entries have multiple group memberships, so the servers will be duplicated in the view for every group membership. I need to return only a single row with the distinct server names and for every group membership, I'd like this concatenated with some kind of delimiter like '|' or ','

I've come up with this (thanks for the link), and I had to scrub out the null entries otherwise the LEN and LEFT functions wouldn't work. Question is, how do I now return all entries (even if nothing is found in 'arms_group')?

```
select server, LEFT(column_names, LEN(column_names )-1) AS column_names
from cmdb.[dbo].v_master_server_list AS extern
CROSS APPLY
(
    select arms_group + ','
    FROM cmdb.[dbo].v_master_server_list AS intern
    where extern.server = intern.server
    FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (column_names)

where arms_group is not null
GROUP BY server, column_names;
```

Comment: You will need to select '`name`' `DISTINCT`, and also use  `GROUP BY` command

Comment: tried group by and get  an error that it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

Comment: can you please show some codes, how did you run it? also give as the table structure

Comment: Hi, here is the table structure of the view, hope its what you need -- https://postimg.org/image/ge3grtr59/

Comment: I'm trying this: select distinct server,arms_group from v_master_server_list

group by server and getting: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'v_master_server_list.ARMS_Group' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`for xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) to [Concatenate Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

```
select distinct
    group_membership
  , servers = stuff(
    (
      select distinct '|'+i.server_name
        from v_master_server_list as i
        where i.group_membership = o.group_membership
        order by i.server_name
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
  from v_master_server_list as o
```

In Sql Server vNext, you can use [`string_agg()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx)